# SkipWhile fails with "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ..."

Tags: linq-to-entities

I cannot find why the following exception occurs. Any help is most appreciated.

```
// EdcsEntities is derived from System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
EdcsEntities db = new EdcsEntities();

var query = from i in db.Colleges
            select i;

query = query.SkipWhile<College>(x => x.CollegeID != 100);

List<College> l = query.ToList<College>();
```

Exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[EDCS.ServiceLayer.DataAccess.College] 
>   SkipWhile[College](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[EDCS.ServiceLayer.DataAccess.College], 
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[EDCS.ServiceLayer.DataAccess.College, System.Boolean]])' 
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: You probably want `Where` instead of `SkipWhile`.

Comment: I want to ignore the elements in the source as long as the condition is true and then returns the remaining elements.

Comment: You may find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227828/how-to-implement-skipwhile-with-linq-to-sql-without-first-loading-the-whole-list) useful. It is for LINQ to SQL, but it should work the same for LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 8):

You can't use `SkipWhile` with EF because there's no good way to translate them to SQL. Since SQL queries return unordered sets (unless you use `ORDER BY`) it doesn't make sense to use predicates like that, so they don't exist.

The way to use `SkipWhile` in EF is to just turn the query into objects with `AsEnumerable()` before calling it:

```
query = query.AsEnumerable().SkipWhile(x => x.CollegeID != 100);
```

Of course you probably want to do something like this:

```
query = query.OrderBy(x => x.CollegeId).Where(x => x.CollegeID > 100);
```

Comment: In this case `Where` and `SkipWhile` have totally different behavior: `Where` returns all the elements with `CollegeId != 100`, `SkipWile` ignores the elements in the source as long as `CollegeId != 100` and then returns the remaining elements as soon as `CollegeId == 100` is found.  Even if in the example above the two methods have the same result, to use one or the other would make a big difference in a case like this: `query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Where(x => x.CollegeID > 100);` as opposed to `query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Name).SkipWhile(x => x.CollegeID > 100);`