# How to implement SkipWhile with Linq to Sql without first loading the whole list into memory?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I need to order the articles stored in a database by descending publication date and then take the first 20 records after the article with `Id == 100`.

This is what I would like to do with Linq:

```
IQueryable<Article> articles = 
    db.Articles
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate)
    .SkipWhile(a => a.Id != 100)
    .Take(20);
```

However, this generates a NotSupportedException because `SkipWhile` is not supported in Linq to Sql (see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/f71d54dd-c901-4de5-a3a7-9e3a61b500bc/)).

A possible solution is to execute the query and then apply `SkipWhile` using Linq to Object:

```
IEnumerable<ArticleDescriptor> articles = 
    db.Articles
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate)
    .ToList()
    .SkipWhile(a => a.Article.Id != 100)
    .Take(20);
```

But this means I need to load the whole ordered list into memory first and then take 20 articles after the one with `Id == 100`.

Is there a way to avoid this huge memory consumption?

More in general, what is the best way to achieve this in SQL?

Comment: Interesting requirement. Is there any relationship between `Id` and `PublicationDate`? Is what you want to do really to order them by date, go along that list till you get to `Id` `100`, and *then* take the next 20?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. There is no relationship between `Id` and `PublicationDate`. The reason for this requirement is that I need to fetch a certain number of articles published after a specified article of which I know only the `Id`. Of course, if I knew the `PublicationDate` of that article, it would be much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If, as I'm guessing from the column name, `PublicationDate` doesn't change, you can do this in two separate queries:

- Establish the `PublicationDate` of the `Article` with `Id == 100`
- Retrieve the 20 articles from that date onwards

Something like:

```
var thresholdDate = db.Articles.Single(a => a.Id == 100).PublicationDate;
var articles = 
    db.Articles
    .Where(a => a.PublicationDate <= thresholdDate)
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate)
    .Take(20);
```

It might even be that LINQ to SQL can translate this:

```
var articles = 
    db.Articles
    .Where(a => a.PublicationDate 
             <= db.Articles.Single(aa => aa.Id == 100).PublicationDate)
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate)
    .Take(20);
```

but that may be too complex for it. Try it and see.

Comment: I think this is a good solution (also posted by @Atzoya), which could be also moved to a stored procedure in the database. I suppose we can't do it with a single SQL query.  The only problem here is in the (unlikely) event we have many articles with different Ids posted at the same time. But to sort this out we need to agree on an extra ordering rule while fetching the articles, like by descending Ids: 

`var articles = 
    db.Articles
    .Where(a => a.PublicationDate <= thresholdDate && a.Id < 100)
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate).ThenByDescending(a => a.Id)
    .Take(20);`

Comment: I tried and it works. LINQ to SQL even manages to translate the entire LINQ query into a single SQL query.

Comment: May I suggest you replace Single(a => a.Id == 100) with Single(aa => aa.Id == 100) to accept this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
var articles = 
    db.Articles
    .Where(a => a.PublicationDate < db.Articles
                                    .Where(aa => aa.Id==100)
                                    .Select(aa => aa.PublicationDate)
                                    .SingleOrDefault())
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate)
    .Take(20);
```

Comment: +1 since this is the same solution as the one posted by AakashM, but the other one has a clearer explanation

Answer (score 0):

Isnt the solution to just add a where statement?

```
IQueryable<Article> articles = db.Articles.Where(a => a.id != 100).OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate).Take(20);
```

Comment: Yeah I thought that too, but look at the actual requirement: order them by date, go along that list till you get to id 100, **then** take the next 20. Weird.

Comment: This will not work if the article 5 was published _after_ the article 10 (due to sitting in draft for example)

Comment: Yeah i missunderstood the question.