# LINQ to SQL SkipWhile implementation with duplicate values in the sort column

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have a list of articles sorted by descending rating. If the rating is the same, they are sorted by ascending ID (the IDs are unique):

```
ID      RATING
9       34
3       32
6       32
8       32
12      32
1       25
2       23
```

I want to query pages of 3 articles, which means the first page will have articles 9, 3 and 6. This is done by querying the top 3 articles form the sorted list.

Now, I want to take the next 3 articles resuming from article 8, using the article ID as marker for where to resume, as opposed to just skipping the first 3 articles. This is because the content of the article table changes very rapidly and a standard pagination approach like this:

```
var articles = 
    db.Articles
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.Rating).ThenBy(a => a.Id)
    .Skip(3)
    .Take(3);
```

would not work reliably because articles can be added or deleted at any time (just assume the rating doesn't change here).

If this was LINQ to Object, I could use `SkipWhile`:

```
var articles = 
    db.Articles
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.Rating).ThenBy(a => a.Id)
    .SkipWhile(a => a.Article.Id != 8)
    .Take(3);
```

but `SkipWhile` is not implemented in LINQ to SQL (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227828/how-to-implement-skipwhile-with-linq-to-sql-without-first-loading-the-whole-list)).

If I did like this:

```
var articles = 
    db.Articles
    .Where(a => a.Rating 
             < db.Articles.Single(aa => aa.Id == 8).Rating)
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.Rating)
    .Take(3);
```

I would skip article 12, while if I did something like this:

```
var articles = 
    db.Articles
    .Where(a => a.Rating 
             <= db.Articles.Single(aa => aa.Id == 8).Rating)
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.Rating)
    .Take(3);
```

I would take articles 3 and 6 twice.

Using LINQ to SQL, what's the best way to resume the pagination from article 8, using the article ID as marker for where to resume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just do:

```
var articles = 
db.Articles
.OrderByDescending(a => a.Rating).ThenBy(a => a.Id)
.Skip(3)
.Take(3);
```

Okay, if that won't work, I'd write a function something like this:

```
    static IEnumerable<Article> GetArticles(List<Article> articles, int articlesToRetrieve, int startingID)
    {
        IEnumerable<Article> results = null;
        results = articles.OrderByDescending(a => a.Rating).ThenBy(a => a.ID);

        if (startingID > 0)
        {
            int lastRating = articles.Single(aa => aa.ID == startingID).Rating;
            results = results.Where(a => a.Rating < lastRating || (a.Rating == lastRating && a.ID > startingID));
        }

        if (articlesToRetrieve > 0)
        {
            results = results.Take(articlesToRetrieve);
        }
        return results;
    }
```

which I think will do the trick.

Comment: No, because after I fetched the first page, someone could have inserted or deleted a row. Using a fixed number in `Skip()`, inserted rows can be skipped or can cause subsequent rows to be repeated and deleted rows can cause subsequent rows to be skipped.