# What is the most efficient way to obtain an ordered range using EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

## Predicament

I have a large dataset that I need to perform a complex calculation upon a part of. For my calculation, I need to take a **chunk of ordered data** from a large set based on input parameters.

My method signature looks like this:

```
double Process(Entity e, DateTimeOffset? start, DateTimeOffset? end)
```

### Potential Solutions

The two following methods spring to mind:

#### Method 1 - WHERE Clause

```
double result = 0d;
IEnumerable<Quote> items = from item in e.Items
                           where (!start.HasValue || item.Date >= start.Value)
                              && (!end.HasValue || item.Date <= end.Value)
                           orderby item.Date ascending
                           select item;
...
return result;
```

#### Method 2 - Skip & Take

```
double result = 0d;
IEnumerable<Item> items = e.Items.OrderBy(i => i.Date);
if (start.HasValue)
    items = items.SkipWhile(i => i.Date < start.Value);
if (end.HasValue)
    items = items.TakeWhile(i => i.Date <= end.Value);
...
return result;
```

## Question

If I were just throwing this together, I'd probably just go with *Method 1*, but the size of my dataset and the the size of the set of datasets are both too large to ignore slight efficiency losses, and it is of vital importance that the resulting enumerable is ordered.

Which approach will generate the more efficient query? And is there a more efficient approach that I am yet to consider?

Any solutions presented can make the safe assumption that the table is well indexed.

Comment: You should use IQueryable<Item> to make sure SQL is generated and the data set isn't loaded into memory. 

You could try using an SQL profiler to look at the generated SQL and run it on your server to look at the execution time.

Comment: Good catch on the IQueryable. I should know better than that. Fixed the question based on that.

Comment: Aaaand then I rolled back, realising that IQueryable doesn't play nice with orderby. I did verify that it's not evaluating early though.

Comment: Because you are using .Date on a DateTime this is native C# code and will need to be loaded into the CLR so will never run in SQL.  You should use the EntityFunctions to create a Date without Time in the OrderBy 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.createdatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Actually, I'm not. What you're looking at is the `Date` property of a hypothetical class `Item`. It is of type `DateTimeOffset`, as implied by the method signature. `DateTimeOffset` will be handled neatly by SQL Server.

Comment: I should note that the types used in this scenario are 100% for the purpose of illustration. I don't need to know about syntax or logic errors I made while writing C# in a web browser. My question is about the relative efficiency of the two approaches presented for the task I want accomplished.

Comment: I would, again, use a Profiler to compare the speed of the two generated queries, and if they are both two slow write a Table View / Stored Procedure to do the job.

Comment: try change the IEnumerable<T> to IQueryable<T>,make it to a lazy query

Comment: That one was already discussed above.

Comment: Are you facing performance problems with the first solution? Maybe check the generated sql on your dbms and create a performance analysis. Maybe your missing some indexes on your table. The OrderBy maybe could be expensive

Comment: I haven't even fully implemented the solution yet. I was just starting to write the method when I wondered if I was going about it the right way, and in my very quick research did not find an answer, so figured I'd pose the question here for the benefit of myself and others. Thanks to everyone who helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SkipWhile` is not supported for translation to SQL. You need to throw that option away.

The best way to go about this is to create an index on the field you use to range select and then issue a query that is SARGable. `where date >= start && date < end` is SARGable and can make use of an index.

`!start.HasValue ||` is not a good idea because that destroys SARGability. Build the query so that this is not needed. For example:

```
if(start != null) query = query.Where(...);
```

Make the index covering and you have optimal performance. There is no single extra row that needs to be processed.

Comment: That first part is the bit I was looking for, thanks :). In my actual code I have the `.HasValue` logic split out, but in my quest for brevity in writing the question, it seems I looked a little silly.

Answer (score 2):

According to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412233/skipwhile-fails-with-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method) you can't use *SkipWhile* without materializing a query, so in 2. case you materialize all entities, then calculate the result.

In 1. scenario you can let sql handle this query and materialize only necessary records, so it's better option.

EDIT:

I wrote sample data, queries made to database:

1. `SELECT 
   [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
   [Project1].[AddedDate] AS [AddedDate], 
   [Project1].[SendDate] AS [SendDate] 
   FROM ( SELECT 
       [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
       [Extent1].[AddedDate] AS [AddedDate], 
       [Extent1].[SendDate] AS [SendDate]

       FROM [dbo].[Alerts] AS [Extent1]
       WHERE ([Extent1].[AddedDate] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[AddedDate] <= @p__linq__1)
   )  AS [Project1]
   ORDER BY [Project1].[AddedDate] ASC`
2. `SELECT 
   [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
   [Extent1].[AddedDate] AS [AddedDate], 
   [Extent1].[SendDate] AS [SendDate]
   FROM [dbo].[Alerts] AS [Extent1]
   ORDER BY [Extent1].[AddedDate] ASC`

I inserted 1 000 000 records, and wrote query with expected 1 row in result. In 1 case query time was 291 ms and instant materialize. In second case query time was 1065 ms and I had to wait about 10 second to materialize result;

Comment: Upvote for the effort and the generated query. I'm sure that will aide understanding :)